# how to use intl flutter without context?

Tags: flutter, intl, flutter-intl

I'm trying to use the intl plugin to get more translations of my app, but it always needs a context. In files without context where I simply have to assign a value to the variable what should I do?

For example I would like to do something like this::

```
String yes = "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.yes}"
```

Comment: you can put this in the `build` method

Comment: Use AppLocalizations.current.yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers suggest you can put your `variable` inside `build`, however, if you don't want to do that then you can define a `Navigator Key` and get the current `context` from it anywhere in your code.

Define Navigator Key:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Attach it to your `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        ...
      ),
```

Get current context from navigatorKey:

```
String yes =  "${AppLocalizations.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!)!.yes}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package, you can use

```
Get.context
```

to get a context in any piece of your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access context outside of build method unless you pass it to a function.

```
  @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       String yes =  "${AppLocalizations.of(context)!.yes}" //like this
         ...
      }
```

if you don't want to do this. you need to change your `AppLocalization` static function.

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately in some circumstances I cannot put my variable inside a build method ... I have files containing only certain functions and attributes and there without context I cannot modify my values

Comment: Share you code and what you want to do. I just edited the answer